# How to make process in compilation-mode think it's not running in interactive terminal?

Tags: process, compilation-mode

I use [minitest-mode](https://github.com/arthurnn/minitest-emacs/blob/master/minitest.el) which [starts](https://github.com/arthurnn/minitest-emacs/blob/1aadb7865c1dc69c201cecee275751ecec33a182/minitest.el#L91-L94) Ruby tests in `compilation-mode`:

```
(compilation-start
 actual-command
 'minitest-compilation-mode
 (lambda (arg) (minitest-buffer-name (or file-name ""))))
```

Tests invoke `psql` program, and it thinks like it's running in interactive terminal, so it [outputs some of its output through pager](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/12a53c732cedf83f70106b5605a5003c2000d7f4/src/fe_utils/print.c#L3293) (`less`). Because `compilation-mode` buffer is not a real interactive terminal, I can't press keys to close `less` and continue, so test process freezes and requires killing.

Is it possible to make `compilation-mode` run program in non-interactive terminal (as I understand, it should not allocate pty)? When looking at `ps` output, it looks like it has its own tty:

```
18046 ttys004    0:02.51 ruby -Ilib:test:spec test/functional/ads_controller_test.rb
18063 ttys004    0:02.41 ruby bin/rails db:test:prepare
```

Comment: Also, the part of the problem is that compilation buffer's tty does not implement `TIOCGWINSZ` ioctl, so `psql` decides to run pager regardless of output size.

Comment: Have you tried putting your compilation buffer in comint mode?  Activate it with C-u M-x compile. This allows you to enter text at the prompt. Also, what is the value of environment variable TERM?

Comment: Perhaps the easiest thing you can do to disable pager is to change `actual-command` to be `sh -c "actual-command"`. Unless `sh` is called with `-i` flag, it will not allocate tty and whatever other programs it will run will not try to second-guess you about pagers etc. Also, something I find myself doing quite often in this situation is running `actual-command | cat`, which also disables pagers.

Comment: @InHarmsWay thanks, activating `comint-mode` allows to interact with terminal, I didn't know about this possibility. `TERM` is set to `dumb`.

Comment: @wvxvw for my case, `sh -c` didn't disable paging, but `| cat` disabled it successfully. In both cases, underlying command (`ruby`) had tty.

Comment: @inharmsway: I wanted to achieve the opposite of OP - I want to have comint in *compilation* and this question comes up top. Your comment gave the solution, and it is awesome! I have used Emacs for decades and didn't know about this - it would have saved me *so* many seconds over the years. I suggest you post an answer with your information (plus a note how to actually make the tty go away to formally answer the question...). I would do it but don't want to steal your credits. :)

Comment: It might help to somehow do the equivalent of export `PAGER=cat`.